# Windows DuplicateHandle named pipe handle strange error 183 "file already exists"

Tags: windows, duplicates, named-pipes, handle

I have a problem with DuplicateHandle (Win32). I try to duplicate a named pipe handle and I always get the Error 183 "file already exists". I do not understand this error message, because I try to create a copy of a file handle and the new file handle does not exist before. (Is there a start value required to overwrite?) This is my call:

```
return DuplicateHandle (MeshellProcessHandle, sourcehandle, HelperProcess, targethandle, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS) != 0;
```

To understand what I am doing, I have to explain more extensively: I am working on a convenient editor frontend for the command line program cmd.exe. This project already works fine on the OS/2 Operating System which is very familiar with Win32, because from a historical point of view, the two OS were developed together until one year before finishing, where Microsoft and IBM went different ways.
The implementation of this program was quite tricky: There's a windowed front end editor program. This program creates named pipes for stderr, stdout and stderr, but from the reverse point of view (output from cmd.exe is input for the editor). Because of limited communication between different sessions, I had to program a "cmd helper program" which is a tiny commandline program holding several API calls and running in the same session as the cmd.exe program. The helper gets the editor process ID via commandline parameter and opens the existing pipes created by the windowed editor program and then redirects stdin/stdout/stderr to the pipes. The helper gets the process handle of the editor from the editor process ID via "OpenProcess" API call. Then the helper executes cmd.exe which automatically inherits the stdin/stdout/stderr handles and now cmd.exe writes to and reads from the pipe.
Another option would be to parse the full pipe names to cmd.exe without using DuplicateHandle, but I would prefer to be as close as to my solution which already works fine on the OS/2 Operating System.

Comment: possible you call `GetLastError` in wrong time. i doubt that `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION` returned by this api

Comment: Don't explain what (you think) you did. Show a [mcve] instead.

Comment: Yes, if I use GetLastError() immediately after the API call, I get another result. Now the error message 5 Access denied is shown. I added in the API call CreateNamedPipe SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES.bInheritHandle = TRUE in the windowed main program, but the DuplicateHandle call in the helper program which should redirect stdin/out to existing named pipes still shows error 5. Any ideas?

Comment: I did not manage the problem yet. I assume that the helper program which has been started separately still has not the rights to duplicate the named pipe file handle.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why I have no access rights to duplicate the pipe handles. But I have found another solution: My helper console program starts the child process (cmd.exe) and within this child process, I want to use the named pipes instead of stdin/stdout/stderr - this is the reason why I want to use DuplicateHandle. Windows offers a convenient solution when starting the child process by using
CreateProcess (...)
With CreateProcess, you have always to hold parameters in the STARTUPINFO structure. And there are three handle variables you can set to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to the three named pipes cmd_std*:

```
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
HFILE cmd_stdout, cmd_stdin, cmd_stderr;

//Open the existing pipes with CreateFile

//Start child process program

    StartupInfo.hStdOutput = &cmd_stdout;
    StartupInfo.hStdInput = &cmd_stdin;
    StartupInfo.hStdError = &cmd_stderr;

    CreateProcess (..., &StartupInfo, ...);
```

This solution has much less code than the variant with DuplicateHandle, because I also have to save and to restore the original file handles, so this way replaces 9 DuplicateHandle calls.

Answer (score 0):

I did program the changes now but my new code described above does not work. If I set the "handle inheritance flag" in CreateProcess to TRUE, cmd.exe does not get executed, but CreateProcess returns TRUE (=OK). Here's my detailed code:

```
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;
HFILE cmd_stdout, cmd_stdin, cmd_stderr;
char *pprogstr, *pargstr;

//Open the existing pipes with CreateFile

//Start child process program cmd.exe
    StartupInfo.hStdOutput = &cmd_stdout;
    StartupInfo.hStdInput = &cmd_stdin;
    StartupInfo.hStdError = &cmd_stderr;
    StartupInfo.dwFlags =  STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    pprogstr = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe";
    pargstr = "/K";
CreateProcess (
        pprogstr,   // pointer to name of executable module
        pargstr,    // pointer to command line string
        NULL,       // pointer to process security attributes
        NULL,       // pointer to thread security attributes
        TRUE,       // handle inheritance flag
        0,          // creation flags
        NULL,       // pointer to new environment block
        NULL,       // pointer to current directory name
        &StartupInfo,        // pointer to STARTUPINFO
        &ProcessInformation) // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

Any idea?

Comment: The observed behaviour is: cmd.exe gets executed, but seems to crash or to end immediately. Do I have to Duplicate the handles first? But all DuplicateHandle calls end in LastError 5 access denied.

Comment: Here is a sample from MSN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output After opening the existing pipe with CreateFile, it is necessary to define the pipe handle to inherited: SetHandleInformation(cmd_stdin, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) for the three pipes stdin, stdout, stderr. But the child still chrases after executing with CreateProcess.